# How to accpet this JSON Object and deserialize it?

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class

**vf page**

```
function createRecord()
{
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    var formData = JSON.stringify(jQuery('#form').serialize()); 
    MyCustomController1.createContact(formData); 
}
```

**controller**

```
@RemoteAction
public static String createContact(String strJsonObjResult)
{
   system.debug('strJsonObjResult='+strJsonObjResult);
}
```

DEBUG OUTPUT:

> strJsonObjResult=[{"name":"firstname","value":"xyz"},{"name":"lastname","value":"xyz"},{"name":"email","value":"xyx@xyz.com"},{"name":"phone","value":"789456"},{"name":"dob","value":"2013-05-13"}]

//its showing me like so how to deserialize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class to parse the input, roughly outlined as follows:

```
public class Item {
    public String name, value;
}
@RemoteAction public static void createContact(String jsonObjResult) {
    // Serialize Items
    Item[] values = (List<Item>)JSON.deserialize(jsonObjResult, List<Item>.class);
    // process items to create contacts
}
```

Note: This would be a lot easier if you used standard JSON notation:

```
{ "FirstName": "xyz", "LastName": "xyz", "Email": "xyx@xyz.com", "Phone": "789456", "BirthDate": "2013-05-13" }
```

Then, you could serialize the object directly:

```
@RemoteAction public static void createContact(String jsonObjResult) {
    Contact record = (Contact)JSON.deserialize(jsonObjResult, Contact.class);
    insert record;
}
```

Comment: User may not change the JSON notation because entire form is serialized which would only take `input` tag attribute `name` and `value` in an array.

Comment: @Ashwani I know that's how they chose to do it, but it'd be easier if they changed the jQuery script to make it easier to process in Apex. I simply offered two different solutions (I'd personally go with the latter, because they don't have to deal with Date vs. String, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Try Below piece of code

**Parser/Wrapper Class**

```
public class JsonParseToApex{
    public class Class_0 {
        public String name; //firstname
        public String value;//xyz
    }
    public class Class_1 {
        public String name; //lastname
        public String value;//xyz
    }
    public class Class_2 {
        public String name; //email
        public String value;//xyx@xyz.com
    }
    public class Class_3 {
        public String name; //phone
        public String value;//789456
    }
    public class Class_4 {
        public String name; //dob
        public String value;//2013-05-13
    }
    public static List<JsonParseToApex> parse(String jsonObjResult){
        JsonParseToApex[] values = (List<JsonParseToApex>)JSON.deserialize(jsonObjResult, List<JsonParseToApex>.class);
        return  values;
    }
}
```

**Method**

```
@RemoteAction public static void createContact(String jsonObjResult) {
    // Call the parse method
    List<JsonParseToApex> wrapperList = JsonParseToApex.parse(jsonObjResult);
    system.debug(wrapperList );
}
```